# Is there a standard method for disabling autofill on address fields?

Tags: html, google-chrome

I'm trying to disable Chrome's autofill feature for an input field that is meant to store an address. Chrome seems to mostly ignore the autocomplete=off setting when it comes to autofill, and the only way I've been able to disable it is to set autocomplete to some string that Chrome doesn't recognize, like the following:

```
<input name="address" autocomplete="somethingRandom" />
```

As far as I can tell this isn't supported by the HTML standard, so I'm looking for a more proper way to achieve this. I'm mostly concerned that a future Chrome update will break this hack.

Comment: HTML attributes should always be Strings like `<input autocomplete='off' />`. Double quotes are also okay, but require me to hit the shift key more.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
autocomplete="chrome-off"
```

Comment: Hi, try to expand your answer, by adding steps and reasons

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input autocomplete="off"></input>
```